# Carousel next/prev buttons and scrolling are not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

The Bootstrap Carousel component displays properly however it won't scroll automatically, and the next/prev buttons do not work. I've read a lot of similar questions but I've run out of ideas as to why this could be happening.

I've made sure that Jquery/Boostrap dependencies are in the right order. I copied and pasted the carousel code from the Bootstrap docs and the only change I made was the images that I'm loading locally.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

</head>
<body>


<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="../assets/dict.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="0">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="../assets/JuveLogo.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `@` Your code is correct & working but you are not able to see next and previous arrow due to more opacity with white color so you need to put **live image urls** or you can check with define **width+height** and **border in red** color.

Comment: I can see the arrows in the code I posted. The carousel displays properly and when I hover over the arrows the mouse icon changes accordingly. However, when I click on them nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Worning code example from w3schools?
Here is a link to their page: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

They have a nice explanation of how the carousel from Bootstrap works :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working example with same of your existing code only changed ***image*** to ***text*** and define *arrow in black color*.

```css
.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next{
  background: #000;
  width: 40px!important;
  height: 40px!important;
  border-radius: 50px;
  top: 50%!important;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Carousel Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container p-3">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <!--Start Carousel  -->
   <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="carousel-item active">
         <h3>Slide #1</h3>
         <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="carousel-item">
         <h3>Slide #2</h3>
         <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.
         </p>
       </div>
       <div class="carousel-item">
         <h3>Slide #3</h3>
         <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.
         </p>
       </div>
     </div>
     <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
     </a>
     <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
       <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
     </a>
   </div>
   <!-- /End Carousel -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work me. It displays properly, just like the code I posted, however nothing happens when I click on the arrows. The only noticeable difference is the that when I click on the arrows, the url changes from "http://localhost:4200/" to "http://localhost:4200/#carouselExampleControls" which was also happening with the code I posted.

Comment: You can try like this also **<div class="carousel-control-prev" data-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-slide="prev">...</div>** it means replace **anchor tag** to **div** and **href** to **data-target** attribute.